# Using value of selection for form action

Tags: php, forms, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list where I'd like to use the value of the option dropdown to determine the destination of the action of a post method form.

```
<form name="scriptform" method="post" action=http://www.mysite.com/newad.php?do=newad&cat=<?php urlencode($_POST['catselect']); ?>" target="_self">"
<div class="blocked">
<select name="catselect">
<option value="0">Please select a Category</option>
<optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>
<option value="14" class="">BMW</option>
<option value="23" class="">Porsche</option>
```

The idea here is to take the option value and use it as the category to create a new ad using newad.php. For some reason php is not supplying the value into the string before I press the submit button and it looks like the value is blank. Would appreciate someone providing a little insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server side scripting language.
It evaluates the scriptlets before rendering the page.
So the value of the selection may be nothing at that point.

Consider using javascript to change the form action each time your select a new value.

Add an onchange event for the dropdown

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//
    change(val) {
        document.scriptform.action = "http://www.mysite.com/newad.php?do=newad&cat="+val;
    }
    //-->
    </script>

    <form name="scriptform" method="post" action=http://www.mysite.com/newad.php?do=newad&cat=" target="_self">"
    <div class="blocked">
    <select name="catselect" onChange="change(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Please select a Category</option>
    <optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>
    <option value="14" class="">BMW</option>
    <option value="23" class="">Porsche</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This not only worked perfectly but it also maintained all of the text block entered on this part of the form. Oddly it doesn't show the number in the URL but it does work perfectly in the end. Thank you very much for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function optionsAlert(){
        var e = document.getElementById("catselect");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(strUser);
        window.location.href="http://www.mysite.com/newad.php?do=newad&cat="+strUser;
    }
</script>
</head>

<form name="scriptform" method="post" >
<select name="catselect" id="catselect" onchange="optionsAlert()"/>
<option value="0">Please select a Category</option>
<optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>
<option value="14" class="">BMW</option>
<option value="23" class="">Porsche</option>
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: This was a good answer but didn't maintain the other form information and I also had a popup alert in IE? I really appreciate the above.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the easy way you can do it so with php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['catselect']))
{

    $path ="newad.php?do=newad&cat=".urlencode($_POST['catselect']);
    header("Location:".$path);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
    document.scriptform.submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="post" name="scriptform">
    <div class="blocked">
    <select name="catselect" onChange="change(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Please select a Category</option>
    <optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>
    <option value="14" class="">BMW</option>
    <option value="23" class="">Porsche</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. This didn't quite work as anticipated. Once you click the dropdown there was a popup produced in IE that said the value number and had to be okayed out. It also doesn't maintain any form information you may want to include along with the submission of the form. Still, this was a pretty good answer, thank you.